# Unexplained difference in photo count in iCloud, iPad storage, and Photo.app

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos

iCloud says I have just over 600 photos. On the iPad's storage it says there are just under 300.

However when I go into Apple's Photos.app apparently I have 1800.

I count 900 though. Why are these numbers different and where are the other 900?

Comment: Apple has a throttle to limit large uploads initially. Have your count been wrong for more than 24 hours ( or at least not getting closer to correct) while the devices are connected to a reliable WiFi network and connected to wall power / charging? This could be a transient issue in many cases by design.

Comment: Also - this may depend on the settings your iPad has - please document in an edit if you have photo stream on, upload burst photos on, iCloud library on. There's not enough detail on your setup to say anything but - contact AppleCare for support. With some detail it might be clear if Melvin is on to something that I'm not seeing - all my devices these numbers track very close to iCloud and Photos app since I enable all the options above everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Check www.icloud.com and make sure that the 1800 amount is in the Photos section. If so then your iPad may have "optimize storage" turned on.

If the photos arent on there then you need check and see which devices you have and the full amount of photos on them all: Mac, iPhone, iPad & iPod.

Lastly if neither of these situations helped, then contact Apple Support and let them know that there is an inconsistency with whats on your iPad and your Mac vs the iCloud. They may refresh your iCloud account.

Comment: Optimize storage has never affected the image count. It does downsample the images or potentially remove the image except for thumbnails - but I've not see that make any difference.

Comment: It does affect the amount of photos since they aren't saved to the device. Image count, is responsible for counting photos on the device, not in the cloud or both.

Comment: Aah. You’re looking at setting app and not iCloud Photo Library in photos app when you say image count?

Comment: Correct since thats where the storage amount is coming from, the amount in settings.

Answer (score 3):

On iOS - I like to get my count from Albums - All Photos - check for the total photos count and videos count at the bottom of the thumbnail list.

(I'm at 20,306 Photos and 449 Videos)

On the iPad I have the same except I'm at 20,305 Photos. To get an explanation, go to the Photos view (as opposed to Memories, Shared or Albums) and tap in to a photo.

As you navigate away from the years view in collections, you'll eventually get to a "Moment" and then can scroll to the newest moment and see more details.

On the phone it says "Upload Paused for 1 item" and a blue **Resume** control if I want to use Cellular Data and finish the upload.

Oddly, the settings app shows 20,318 so I’ve somehow got another dozen “photos”being counted in settings app.